# Is there any way to check webpage content health check in AWS lambda/drs/ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, failover

My website returns a status code of 200 OK even when the server crashes or freezes. I was hunting for a failover solution on AWS and came across Elastic Disaster Recovery Service. It can manually initiate failover, but in order to automate the procedure in the event of a crash, I'm seeking for feasible customized solutions for a website health check. Webserver is in EC2. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

1. Cannot use load balancer because enterprise license is limited to 1 instance.
2. Tried DNS failover method, but it was unreliable.

Comment: If you only have one license, what is it supposed to fail-over to exactly?

Comment: Sometimes parallel batch calls make the service crash for clients.

Comment: That's a problem statement that describes why your service crashes. That doesn't explain where AWS is supposed to fail-over to if the service crashes. It sounds like you need to have your server reboot, or restart your service after a crash or something, instead of failing-over to another server, since you can only run this software on one server.